# Oracle SQLPLUS - How do I output header only once when spooling more than 50,000 records?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am spooling a large result to disk and want to include the headers only once. I want headings but only once, not every 50,000 records.  Based on the documentation I seem to be limited to 50,000 records before the header is printed a second time.  According to the [documentation 50,000 is the highest value.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SQL-Plus-limits.html#GUID-93CA1BD6-888F-40FD-B57F-0B782C96854F)

I've tried setting the pagesize to zero and headings on - but that still produces a file with no header:

```
set pagesize 0
set heading on
```

Ideally I want to be able to perform a line count on the output file in unix:

```
wc -l result-file.txt
```

and it equals the Number of records in the query + 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply UNION the headers to the query itself, as in:

```
SELECT 'FIRST COLUMN' AS COLUMN1,
       'NEXT COLUMN' AS COLUMN2,
       'OTHER COLUMN' AS COLUMN3
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT a.COLUMN1,
       a.COLUMN2,
       b.COLUMN3
  FROM TABLE1 a
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 b
    ON b.KEY_FIELD = a.KEY_FIELD
```

Done this way you'll get the headers first followed by all the 'real' data.

Comment: Thanks for this, one drawback is datatypes.  I would need to convert the data query to match the headings datatype.  I wonder if there is a 'hint' in the SQL that could trick it; like those csv hints.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

- first select headings,
- then rest of data - before that select, `set pagesize 0`

Drawback is an empty line (that contains only separators). I don't know how to get rid of it.

Here you go:

p.sql

```
-- general settings
set termout off 
set feedback off
set colsep ';'

-- headings
col empno format a10
col ename format a10
col salary format a10
spool emps.txt
select null as empno, null as ename, null as salary from dual;

-- data
set pagesize 0
col empno format 99999
col ename format a10
col salary format 999G990
select empno, ename, sal from emp;
spool off
```

Calling the script:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╚et Lis 24 19:31:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> @p
SQL>
```

Result:

```
EMPNO     ;ENAME     ;SALARY                                                    
----------;----------;----------                                                
          ;          ;                          --> this is line I'm talking about                                   
  7369;SMITH     ;       800                                                    
  7499;ALLEN     ;      1600                                                    
  7521;WARD      ;      1250                                                    
  7566;JONES     ;      2975                                                    
  7654;MARTIN    ;      1250                                                    
  7698;BLAKE     ;      2850                                                    
  7782;CLARK     ;      2450                                                    
  7788;SCOTT     ;      3000                                                    
  7839;KING      ;      5000                                                    
  7844;TURNER    ;      1500                                                    
  7876;ADAMS     ;      1100                                                    
  7900;JAMES     ;       950                                                    
  7902;FORD      ;      3000                                                    
  7934;MILLER    ;      1300
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in "pagesize 0".Details here https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re66.html

> Issuing a SET PAGESIZE 0 command also turns off headings. If you want to enable >headings and SET HEADING ON doesn’t appear to be working, you should check the >pagesize as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please run following command then run your SQL:
set pagesize 999

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32769358)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another variant first select headings, then rest of data:

```
-- for scv spool with only first head, use two parts:
    
set pagesize 10
--According to the documentation pagesize= 50,000 is the highest value.
set UNDERLINE off
SET COLSEP ','
set trimout on
SET TERMOUT OFF
set head on 
    
-- first - columns heads:
spool &1..csv
    
--select 'Date, Read, Write, Total' from dual; - instead of this
    
select * from (
  @&1._body.sql
) where rownum <2;
    
spool off
    
set head off 
set pagesize 0
    
-- than only data
spool &1..csv append
    
select * from (
  @&1._body.sql
) where rownum <100000;
    
spool off
```